# openauth support in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, oauth

Is there any native support for openauth in google app engine?

If so, where are the details?

If not, then please suggest alternatives?

I am planning to use this with twitter

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean OAuth?

Yes, the standard [Python OAuth library](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) is compatible with App Engine.

[tornado.auth](http://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/auth.py) and [gaema](http://code.google.com/p/gaema/) go a step further with specific support for authenticating to Twitter's OAuth implementation from App Engine.

Comment: OAuth support is now included as an experimental feature of AppEngine: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html

Comment: "Using Google Accounts and a simple API, any App Engine application can be an OAuth service provider.". Authenticating to Twitter would be implementing a consumer.